# Regarding Spacy's part of speech

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, spacy, data-extraction

I am parsing a data using Spacy. I have to extract all the nouns and adjectives but I am getting some unusual results for some words. For example, 'use' is coming as NOUN instead of VERB, also I want 'Left' as an adjective instead of verb like for 'right' in right knee pain. Is there a way to do this?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(u'Alcohol use. Left knee pain. Right knee pain')
for word in doc:
   print(word.text, word.pos_)

Output:
    Alcohol NOUN
   use NOUN
   . PUNCT
   Left VERB
   knee NOUN
   pain NOUN
   . PUNCT
   Right ADJ
   knee NOUN
   pain NOUN
```

Comment: In the phrase "alcohol use", "use" would normally be interpreted as a noun (it's the same as "use of alcohol"). While your text is not like what spaCy's models are trained on and it's normal to have trouble with it, you might also need to adjust your expectations.

Comment: @polm23 Thank you for the help. Is there a way to handle such a problem? If not spacy then there would surely be other way to handle such problems.

Comment: These are not complete sentences, and since it's impossible for a human to determine the parts of speech, it is also impossible for a computer.  As the other commenters said, it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accuracy of POS tagging is not 100%. It is around 97% only. So we should expect these kinds of behaviours. Also, the sentences you used for testing are ambiguous even for a human being.

If you use more advanced models like `en_core_web_md` or `en_core_web_lg` you will get more accuracy. In your case you will get 'Left' as an adjective if you use any of these models instead of default 'en' model.

Comment: @jishadThank you. It worked for 'Left' but for 'use', it is still showing as NOUN. Anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a way to extract   'Family history Arthritis' from the given line? 

          1. Family history of Arthritis (M19.90) : Mother

Comment: this shoudl be another question but > Family history Arthritis. that sounds like you just want to remove stopwords. 
```  for token in doc:
    if not token.is_stop and not token.is_punct:
```